# unscrew the over-tightened nuts from a Hyundai Santa Fe 2012 Limited

Tags: tires, hyundai, spare-tire, wrench, impact-wrench

I [posted a question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/76315/can-i-change-a-regular-tire-rather-than-a-spare-tire-on-a-hyundai-santa-fe-limi) a few days back because my Hyundai Santa Fe 2012 Limited has a flat tire.

I've decided to send the car to a car shop for a tire-change after reading the responses. Now the new issue is that I couldn't unscrew the nuts from the tire in question because they were too much tightened up.

The tool at my hand and used is a toque wrench but it seems not enough! In all fairness I did look up and found [this](https://www.hyundai-forums.com/threads/wheel-lug-nuts-over-tightened.430449/) seems relevant.

Still I failed to gather what is the best course of action and what is the right tool for this job.

Below are some pictures to give you some idea.

The tire:
[image]

torque wrench
[image]

Comment: Only use a torque wrench to put them on, you may damage it,  use a 24" breaker bar to remove them.

Comment: Essential safety advice: if you are doing this with hand tools, leave the car on its wheels until you have freed the nuts, then jack it up. Otherwise you are likely to knock it off the jacks. (A work colleague made that mistake taking the rear wheels off a Lotus sports car, and ended up with the complete fiber glass floor panel cracked from front to back, and the exhaust system inside the car!!)

Answer (score 1):

A cross type lug wrench will work better. You pull up on one side and down on the other so it only applies torque with no bending moment as your wrench. Crosses have 3 or 4 different size sockets , make sure you get one the fits your lugs. And best with wheel on the ground . Brake the lugs free then lift the wheel to unthread the nuts.I put a little grease on the threads but not everyone agrees. The air wrenches at the shops should be adjusted so that they do not over-tighten , but it happens.